# vsftpd cannot connect to server

Tags: linux, ftp, vsftpd

```
# uname -a
Linux localhost 4.19.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u2 (2019-11-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux
# apt install vsftpd
```

I've only changed the following parameter in `vi /etc/vsftpd.conf`

```
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO
local_enable=YES
userlist_deny=NO
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.user_list
```

:wq

```
# touch /etc/vsftpd.user_list
# vi /etc/vsftpd.user_list

ftpuser
```

:wq

```
adduser ftpuser --home /var/www/html --shell /bin/false --no-create-home
```

Password: ftpuser

```
systemctl restart vsftpd
systemctl status vsftpd -> Active: active (running)
```

I'm connecting per filezilla windows client to:

```
Server: x
Username: ftpuser
Password: ftpuser
Port: 21
```

...

```
Error: Cannot connect to server
```

In `@localhost:/# tail -f /var/log/vsftpd.log` also is nothing.

I have also allowed iptables https://serverfault.com/questions/38398/allowing-ftp-with-iptables

What did I do wrong or forgot?